# pgAgent doesn't run on another database than "postgres"

Tags: postgresql-9.3, pgadmin, pgagent

I run a postgreSQL 9.3.3 database and I want to do some automatic Tasks with pgAgent, but it doesn't run on another database than "postgres" db. What can I do to run pgAgent on another db ?

thanks !

Comment: `code`
DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 1, free - 0, deleted - 0
DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
DEBUG: Sleeping...
DEBUG: Clearing inactive connections
DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 1, free - 0, deleted - 0
DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
DEBUG: Sleeping...`code`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to run pgAgent as a different user than "postgres"?

Comment: Yes it's that ! 
I think the problem is that the 'OWNER' of my **pgagent** is _postgres_ and it might be the _otherDB_

Comment: follow this link: [pgAgentlinktoAnotherdatabase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733122/delete-record-36-hours-after-insert-in-postgres-using-triggers/37827426#37827426)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is that the `maintenance DB`'s server (*when you right click on server --> properties --> the 5th row*) is `postgres` and it might be the other database where you want to run `pgagent jobs`.